# What does Keras Concatenate actually do?

Tags: keras

A simple question, but what does Keras Concatenate actually do?. If I have two input layers with size 200 each and pass them through a concat layer what has actually happened? Does it just mean the output of the concatenated layer is treated as a single layer of size 400? When is concat useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you described, the layer is treated as a single layer of size 400. See [here](https://keras.io/layers/merge/).

It's useful for a variety of different structures. [Here](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/bigan/bigan.py) is an example of it being used in a Keras implementation of BiGAN. (Line 105).

Related: You are more likely to see it in architectures that are not simple sequences of layers. Check out the [Functional API Guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), which has many examples of `concatenate` in action.